# Announcing an upcoming election

Tags: discussion

**Summary**: Martial Arts Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **October 4**, as your "graduation" election (as a result of [having lost your beta label](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/589/5714) a while back).

The timeline:

- On September 27, I'll post a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.
- Starting on October 4, users can [nominate themselves](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/election/1). The top questions collected on the previous week will be compiled into a second Meta post, so that potential moderators can answer them.
- On October 11, if there are four or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, we'll extend the nomination period for one more week. If at the end of this extension period there are still not four or more candidates, I'll simply cancel the election and check with the moderation team on who's sticking around and how many extra hands might be needed, and appoint the appropriate number of candidates as pro-tem mods (for full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections)). (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on October 19 (or on the 26th, if we need to extend the nomination period and only get 4 or more candidates then).

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: Waiting with bated breath here.

Comment: As a side note, on the Physical Fitness SE, we had the situation of only three people nominating themselves, and indeed, the election got cancelled. Kicking myself now for not throwing my hat in the ring, at least to enable others.